# Deedle, F# and read csv

Tags: f#, deedle

I am facing an issue when I try to use the function Deedle.Frame.ReadCsv

I am trying to use the overload here: https://collective2.com/c2explorer_help/html/806c0295-1a9f-1bf4-50eb-a221419abe06.htm

```
let schemaSource = "dateRep (DateTime),,,,,,,,,"
let dataSource = Deedle.Frame.ReadCsv(path = "data.csv", schema = schemaSource)
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
error FS0503: A member or object constructor 'ReadCsv' taking 0 arguments is not accessible from this code location. All accessible versions of method 'ReadCsv' take 9 arguments.
```

What I do not get is that all but path are optional. If I use just:

```
Deedle.Frame.ReadCsv("data.csv")
```

It then works...
Any idea? I tried to find some resources on using overloaded functions from other .Net languages with optional parameters but I have not been successful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the Intellisense/Signature shown in Visual Studio was wrong but using **location =** works...